# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

What is the correct way to cast `json` string to object before store to local database?

This is the output for `i['created_by_user']`:

```
{id: 3, name: A}
```

I trying to cast it to `CreatedBy` object

```
 CreatedBy.fromJson(jsonDecode(i['created_by_user'])),
```

**CreatedBy**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class CreatedBy{
  var name;
  var id;
   
  CreatedBy();

  factory CreatedBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CreatedByFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CreatedByToJson(this);
}
```

Here my local table column

```
TextColumn get createdByUser =>
              text().map(const CreatedBySqlConverter()).nullable()();
    
    
    class CreatedBySqlConverter extends TypeConverter<CreatedBy, String> {
      const CreatedBySqlConverter();
    
      CreatedBy mapToDart(String fromDb) {
        if (fromDb == null) return null;
        return CreatedBy.fromJson(json.decode(fromDb));
      }
    
      String mapToSql(CreatedBy createdBy) => json.encode(createdBy.toJson());
    }
```

**Error**

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in fromJson() you need a Map<String, dynamic> and the output of

```
i['created_by_user'] //is a Map<String, dynamic>
```

I think You don't have to decode it.

I would suggest you to replace

```
CreatedBy.fromJson(jsonDecode(i['created_by_user'])),
```

with

```
CreatedBy.fromJson(i['created_by_user']),
```